# jQuery: Is it possible to use slideUp and append text at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user mouses over a picture, I want to `slideUp` a description, so that new text will appear. When the user mouses out, the description will `slideDown`.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$pic1.hover(function () {
        var text1 = $("<div>Price1:$100</div>").hide();
        text1.appendTo($('.this')).slideUp("slow");
    },function () {
        $(this).slideDown();
    }
);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I googled around, but couldn't find anything. Is it possible to use `slideUp` and `slideDown` to show and hide the text?

Comment: can you also provide your html or maybe also a jsfiddle?

Comment: Did anyone here answer your question or are you still in search of a solution?

Comment: thank you everyone :)
my solution is that i use "animate top" to up the pic and hide the text1 <div> with css:z-index under the pic.
then when i hover the pic go top and the text1 div will show up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qvbgb/3/

**HTML**

```
<div class="imgcontainer">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="link.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h3>Product name</h3>
        <p>Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.text').hide();

    $('.container').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.image').slideUp(); 
            $(this).find('.text').slideDown();
        },function () {
            $(this).find('.text').slideUp();
            $(this).find('.image').slideDown();
        }
    );
})
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    min-width : 150px;
    min-height : 150px;
    width : 150px;
    height : 150px;
    cursor : pointer;
    display : block;
}

.image img{
    width : 150px;
    height : 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to use CSS transitions. They're lightweight and easy to do. You can read the specification on transitions [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties). Here is a [quick guide](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) on the matter.

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/5cf5Z/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="imageDiv">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
    <div class="imageDescription">
        What a lovely kitty kat!
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imageDiv {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}
.imageDescription {
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: top 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease;
    transition: top 0.5s ease;
    
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    color: #f7f7f7;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    top: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.imageDiv:hover .imageDescription {
    display: block;
    top: 93%;
}
```

There a few key things that make this work. First, a CSS transition is used. Transitions are written in the following form:

```
transition: [property] [duration] [timing-function] [delay];
```

As can be seen in the example above, I used a `transition` that targeted the `top` attribute. I gave it a `0.5s` duration and an `ease` effect. However, this alone wouldn't produce the effect, as the description would just sit below the image and move up on hover. We don't want to see the description until the user hovers over the image!

To address this, you need to add `overflow: hidden;` to the parent `div.imageDiv`. This hides the image description, until the transition, when it will be slide up, causing it to no longer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

slideUp() will only hide an element, and slideDown() will only show an element. If you want to show an element with slideUp effect or hide with slideDown effect, you have to explicitly call it:

```
$(text1).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
$(text1).hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
```