# text over image showing on hover state

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to have a bit of text showing over the images on the hover state (http://francescaponzini.com/kay/). 
So far I've managed to do it with css. However, I am struggling with the positioning. I'd like the text to show when the user hover any point of the image. I've tried to used the position absolute and relative but without success.

Is there a way to have the div that contains the text assume the same dimension of the image if this makes sense?

this is my code so far:

```
<a class="image_link" href="http://francescaponzini.com/kay/?p=106">
    <img src="http://francescaponzini.com/kay/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Firstname.png" width="450" height="575" alt="" style="width: 243px;">      
    <div class="text-content">Place Name</div>
</a>
```

any help or hint appreciated!thanks to all.

Comment: Please show the relevant CSS in the question

Comment: I wrote a answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24794985/jquery-is-it-possible-to-use-slideup-and-append-text-at-the-same-time/24795314#24795314). If you don't want the transition, the only CSS you need it `#parentDiv:hover #description { display:block}` and `#description {display: none;}`, along with the correct positioning for `#description`.

Comment: He has to remove `opacity:0` too from .text-content.

Comment: @Luxelin thank you very much guys! it s now working and I can now style it properly! :)

Comment: @Alek you ve been really helpful too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.image_link:hover .text-content {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `display` of the wrapping link and give a postition:

```
body.home .hentry > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    ...
}
```

Position the content block and make it fill the wrapping element:

```
.text-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    /* Remove width and height declarations */
    ...
}
```

Comment: I feel I may have misinterpreted "is there a way to have the div that contains the text assume the same dimension of the image"...

Comment: I am trying to have the bit of text showing on the hover state centered within the image - that's why I think I need the div .text-content to be the same dimension of the image_link. But I might be wrong...